# Add Data Provider in DotNetNuke 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, data-access-layer

I'm new to DNN and have started with the new templates written by Chris Hammond for developing DNN modules. I want to separate the tables in the database and have the DNN tables start with the prefix dnn_ and my own tables without this prefix. I can't figure out on how to set this up? Does anyone know?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 1):

Michael, If you want to use my templates without the DNN_ in front of your tables, simply remove the references (in the project) to the word objectQualifier.

You'll likely remove them in the SQLDATAPROVIDER.CS file, and in the SQL scripts themselves.

If you're using DAL2 however, it might be more involved.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your answer. I'm using the DAL2 templates and wants to have the DNN tables with the prefix and my own data tables that should be managed from DNN without prefix. E.g The DNN table Users should be named dbo.dnn_Users and my table Product as dbo.Product. Is it possible to add another dataprovider when using the DAL2 approach? Thanks, Michael

Comment: I really haven't gone into the DAL2 code enough to know unfortunately